# Find $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin|2x-\alpha| dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the value of the definite integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin|2x-\alpha|  dx$$ where $\alpha \in [0,\pi]$.

I'm not sure how to deal with the modulus sign.Any suggestion?
I applied King's rule too but doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: Split the integral into two parts, one over the interval $[0,\frac{\alpha}{2}]$ and ond over the interval $[\frac{\alpha}{2},\pi]$. The integrand for the first integral is $\sin(\alpha-2x)$ and for the second interval $\sin(2x-\alpha)$

Answer (score 0):

**Principle:**
$|x|=x$ if $x>0$
and $|x|=-x$ if $x<0$[image]

**Here,**

$2x-\alpha>0$ if
$x>\alpha/2$
and
$2x-\alpha<0$ if
$x<\alpha/2$

$|2x-\alpha|=2x-\alpha$ if
$x>\alpha/2$

$|2x-\alpha|=-(2x-\alpha)$  if
$x<\alpha/2$

Spliting,
$\int_{0}^{\alpha/2}\sin|2x-\alpha|dx$+$\int_{\alpha/2}^{\pi/2}\sin|2x-\alpha|dx$